# How can I layout some divs in the following arrangment?

Tags: html, css

I have a main container div in the center of my webpage.  This is already in place and has various elements in it.

However, now I'm trying to place a large content div (Div #1) on the left that takes about 70% of the Main Container Div.  What I'm having difficulty doing is getting the CSS right for having Div's #1, #2, #3, and #4 arranged like the following image:

[image]

What should I do in this case for CSS concerning Div #1 - #4?  Should I float Div #1 left, and set it as a percentage/fixed width?  And float divs #2 - 4 right?

Some guidance with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say 2 wrappers div "left" and "right" floating left with correct sizes.

Put div 1 in left

Put div 2, 3 and 4 in right.

This should work, if not let me know

Comment: Just to give that as code:
<div id="left"><div id="1"></div></div><div id="right"><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div></div>

Comment: Gah! Don't use "left" and "right" as ID or class values! Otherwise a sound idea.

Comment: I'm interested in that, why not use something like left, right? Not meaningful enough?

Comment: I said left and right but you can use whatever depending on your business logic

Comment: @merkuro it's like using a class name of "red", what happens when you decide that actually that needs to be blue? "content" and "sidebar" would have been better, but as you say it depends on your logic.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example, that might help you:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">     
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
        <title>Floating</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      *{
       margin:0;
       padding:0; 
      }
      .content{
        padding:10px;
        margin-top:50px;
        width:770px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border:1px solid black;
      }
      .content h1{
        text-align:center; 
      }

      .content h2{
        text-align:center; 
      }

      .content .left{
        width:600px;
        float:left; 
        border:1px solid black;      
      }

      .content .right{
        width:150px;
        float:right;
      }

      .content .right div{        
        margin-bottom:10px; 

        border:1px solid black;
      }
      .content .clear{
        clear:both; 
      }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Main Container Div</h1>
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Div #1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="right"> 
        <div><p>Div #2</p></div>
        <div><p>Div #3</p></div>
        <div><p>Div #4</p></div>
        <div><p>Div #5</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw. marcgg was way faster and this is basically his idea!